# Appendices appear in sub-toc of previous chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I want to have a sub table of contents at the head of each chapter. I did this by using the `titletoc` package and redefining chapter. This works fine in the main matter, but when I add appendices, the title of each appendix appears in the mini table of contents of the previous chapter.

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\makeatletter
\let\stdchapter\chapter
\renewcommand*\chapter{%
    \@ifstar{\starchapter}{\@dblarg\nostarchapter}}
\newcommand*\starchapter[1]{\stdchapter*{#1}}
\def\nostarchapter[#1]#2{%
    \stdchapter[{#1}]{#2}
    \startcontents[chapters]
    \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter with a nice table of contents}
\section{A section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\section{Another section}

\chapter{A chapter that has the first appendix in its table of contents}
\section{A section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\section{Another section}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{An appendix}
\section{A section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\section{This appendix has the second appendix in its table of contents}

\chapter{The second appendix}
\section{A section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\section{Another section}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

How can I avoid getting the title of appendix n in the mini table of contents of appendix n-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- `appendices` uses the `appendix` toc entry type, not `chapter`, so the chapter entries from `appendix` chapters go to the wrong place in the `.ptc` file. This can be solved by `\let\l@appendix\l@chapter`
- Use an explicit `\stopcontent[chapters]` before `\begin{appendices}` to prevent the first appendix appearing neverless in the previous chapter toc.

---

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\makeatletter
\let\stdchapter\chapter
\renewcommand*\chapter{%
    \@ifstar{\starchapter}{\@dblarg\nostarchapter}}
\newcommand*\starchapter[1]{\stdchapter*{#1}}
\def\nostarchapter[#1]#2{%
    \stdchapter[{#1}]{#2}
    \startcontents[chapters]%
    \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter with a nice table of contents}
\section{A section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\section{Another section}

\chapter{Another chapter with a nice table of contents}
\section{A section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\section{Another section}


\chapter{A chapter that has the first appendix in its table of contents}
\section{A section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\section{Another section}


\makeatletter
\let\l@appendix\l@chapter
\makeatother
\stopcontents[chapters]
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{An appendix}
\section{A section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\section{This appendix has the second appendix in its table of contents}

\chapter{The second appendix}
\section{A section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\section{Another section}

\chapter{The third appendix}
\section{A section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\section{Another section}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```